# how to make an offscreen tab/pane slide into the main window on mouse hover in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm making a video player, and I need a list to slide onto the screen when required(on mouse hover).

refer to the below images for more clarity.

[image: a]

I kind of have an inkling of how I can achieve this, but I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way.

my way involves hiding a pane offscreen and then using a for loop to changes it's locating when a mouse hovers over it.
but for that, I need to keep a bit of the full pane on screen, rather just a tab, as shown above, and using a for loop doesn't seem that elegant.

So what is the most efficient way to achieve a task like this?

Comment: what's the problem exactly? and what did you try? not answerable without [mcve] ..

Comment: @kleopatra it's not a bug in the code, it's just a question about which way works best, I already explained what is needed and what I tried in the question

Comment: [JFoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/) has something similar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgV8dDP9DtM. I have never used it though.

Comment: then your question is definitely off scope here and will be closed ...

Comment: okay, any idea where I should post a question like this? @kleopatra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a job for a [TranslationTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) animation:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Side;

import javafx.util.Duration;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class PlaylistDemo
extends Application {
    private static final Duration ANIMATION_SPEED = Duration.seconds(0.5);

    private enum ExpandState { EXPANDED, HIDDEN, CHANGING }

    private ExpandState expandState = ExpandState.HIDDEN;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Object> musicList = new TableView<>();
        musicList.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<Object, Object>("Name"));
        musicList.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<Object, Object>("Artist"));
        musicList.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<Object, Object>("Album"));

        Region playlist = new BorderPane(musicList);
        playlist.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        playlist.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");

        Label tabLabel = new Label("PlayList");
        Tab playlistTab = new Tab(null, playlist);
        playlistTab.setGraphic(tabLabel);
        playlistTab.setClosable(false);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(playlistTab);
        tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);
        tabPane.setRotateGraphic(true);

        // Placeholder, to reserve space for playlist tab.
        TabPane dummyTabPane = new TabPane(new Tab("Dummy", new Label()));
        dummyTabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);
        dummyTabPane.setVisible(false);

        Label player = new Label("Music player goes here");
        player.setPadding(new Insets(200));

        BorderPane musicPane =
            new BorderPane(player, null, dummyTabPane, null, null);
        BorderPane.setMargin(player, new Insets(0, 24, 0, 0));

        StackPane applicationPane = new StackPane(musicPane, tabPane);

        playlist.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((o, old, b) -> {
            double tabWidth = playlist.localToScene(b).getMinX() -
                tabPane.localToScene(0, 0).getX();
            tabPane.setTranslateX(applicationPane.getWidth() - tabWidth);
        });
        applicationPane.widthProperty().addListener((o, old, width) -> {
            double tabWidth =
                playlist.localToScene(playlist.getLayoutBounds()).getMinX() -
                tabPane.localToScene(0, 0).getX();
            tabPane.setTranslateX(applicationPane.getWidth() - tabWidth);
        });

        tabLabel.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            if (expandState == ExpandState.HIDDEN) {
                TranslateTransition transition =
                    new TranslateTransition(ANIMATION_SPEED, tabPane);
                transition.setByX(-playlist.getWidth());

                expandState = ExpandState.CHANGING;
                transition.setOnFinished(ae -> {
                    expandState = ExpandState.EXPANDED;
                });

                transition.play();
            }
        });

        playlist.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            if (expandState == ExpandState.EXPANDED) {
                TranslateTransition transition =
                    new TranslateTransition(ANIMATION_SPEED, tabPane);
                transition.setByX(playlist.getWidth());

                expandState = ExpandState.CHANGING;
                transition.setOnFinished(ae -> {
                    expandState = ExpandState.HIDDEN;
                });

                transition.play();
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(applicationPane));
        stage.setTitle("Player");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(PlaylistDemo.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted, so much better than my for loop idea!

Comment: Hey, your code is great and it works flawlessly, however I've been having trouble mirroring it, That is to have that tab slide in from the left of screen. I was hoping maybe you could help me with that?